# Объявление массива в C++

Tags: массивы, c++

Как объявить массив строк в C++?

Comment: @ivan31, судя по предыдущим вопросам об изменении числа в предпоследней строке файла на bash и C++, перед Вами стоит некая конкретная задача.

Настоятельно рекомендую сначала прочитать учебники, а уже потом задавать вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* array [] = {"123", "456", "789"};
```

Comment: а что за *? я на крестах не пишу, просто интересно

Comment: массив указателей на ``char``

Comment: @fogbit Эта конструкция и не в "крестах" легальна.

Comment: @fogbit, вот Вы в ответе продемонстрировали массив указателей на строковые константы, размерность которого неявно задается на стадии компиляции.

Предыдущие вопросы TC видели ? 

Наверняка следующим будет, *как прочесть файл в массив строк C++ ?*

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] Massiv = new string[<тут целое число - количество элементов>];
```

Comment: В C++ это не сработает...это вам не C# !

Comment: `string *Massiv = new string[<тут целое число - количество элементов>];`